# Getting the closest time each day

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database that looks something like this:

```
Timestamp             Value
2020-12-02 10:01:15   100
2020-12-02 9:59:17    200
2020-12-01 10:02:34   300
2020-12-01 9:59:46    400
2020-11-30 10:00:48   500
2020-11-30 9:58:55    600
```

I'm looking for an SQL query that gets me the value closest to 10AM every day that doesn't go beyond 10AM. Essentially, looking for this result:

```
Timestamp            Value
2020-12-02 9:59:17   200
2020-12-01 9:59:46   400
2020-11-30 9:58:55   600
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'd appreciate the help. If it helps, I'm using MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp)
                   from t as t2
                   where datevalue(t2.timestamp) = datevalue(t.timestamp) and
                         hour(t2.timestamp) < 10
                  );
```